# Two separated Conditions in One IF (VBA Access 2010)

Tags: vba, if-statement, ms-access-2010, conditional-statements

I have two conditions in a form (VBA Access 2010) that both of them work separately.
I put these conditions in "On Load" event of same form and seek time.
The first "If" works (related to "Pr330USD" field) but other field (ExpireDate) does not work.
"Pr330USD" is a numerical field and
"ExpireDate" is a date field.

in below are the codes:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

If Me.Pr330USD.Value = "0" Then

    OpenReportFRR.Enabled = False
    OpenFRRDraft.Enabled = True

ElseIf Me.ExpireDate.Value = "" Then

    ValidDateSchedule.Enabled = False
    VDScheduleTable.Enabled = False

Else

    OpenReportFRR.Enabled = True
    OpenFRRDraft.Enabled = False
    ValidDateSchedule.Enabled = True
    VDScheduleTable.Enabled = True

End If

End Sub

....................

Private Sub Pr330USD_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

If [Pr330USD].Value = "0" Then

    OpenReportFRR.Enabled = False
    OpenFRRDraft.Enabled = True

Else

    OpenReportFRR.Enabled = True
    OpenFRRDraft.Enabled = False

End If

End Sub

....................

Private Sub ExpireDate_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

If Me.ExpireDate.Text = "" Then

    ValidDateSchedule.Enabled = False
    VDScheduleTable.Enabled = False

Else

    ValidDateSchedule.Enabled = True
    VDScheduleTable.Enabled = True

End If

End Sub

....................
```

I wanna know what happened and what is the solution?

Thanks before I you advise me ....

Kasra

Comment: Only one block of your `If` can execute - if more than one test can be true then write them as separate `If`'s

Comment: also try `IsNull(Me.ExpireDate)`

Comment: Thank you dear Tim .. I try that

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it should read:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    If Me.Pr330USD.Value = "0" Then
        OpenReportFRR.Enabled = False
        OpenFRRDraft.Enabled = True
    Else
        OpenReportFRR.Enabled = True
        OpenFRRDraft.Enabled = False
    End If
    If IsNull(Me.ExpireDate.Value) Then
        ValidDateSchedule.Enabled = False
        VDScheduleTable.Enabled = False
    Else
        ValidDateSchedule.Enabled = True
        VDScheduleTable.Enabled = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you dear Gustav !!

Your codes work correctly and better than my recently codes !! :)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the order of rows and conditions structure
and it seems this code is works:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

If Me.Pr330USD.Value <> "0" And Me.ExpireDate <> "" Then

    OpenReportFRR.Enabled = True
    OpenFRRDraft.Enabled = False
    ValidDateSchedule.Enabled = True
    VDScheduleTable.Enabled = True

ElseIf Me.Pr330USD.Value <> "0" And Me.ExpireDate = "" Then

    OpenReportFRR.Enabled = True
    OpenFRRDraft.Enabled = False
    ValidDateSchedule.Enabled = False
    VDScheduleTable.Enabled = False

ElseIf Me.Pr330USD.Value = "0" And Me.ExpireDate <> "" Then

    OpenReportFRR.Enabled = False
    OpenFRRDraft.Enabled = True
    ValidDateSchedule.Enabled = True
    VDScheduleTable.Enabled = True

Else

    OpenReportFRR.Enabled = False
    OpenFRRDraft.Enabled = True
    ValidDateSchedule.Enabled = False
    VDScheduleTable.Enabled = False

End If

End Sub
```